# Visual Studio Plugin for writing Arduino Code

Tags: gratis, c++, visual-studio, plug-in

I am programming stuff for Arduino, most often it's just a small project, so the [official Arduino IDE](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software) is sufficient.

However, sometimes I have larger projects and I need features which are not available in Arduino IDE such as

- renaming variables
- renaming methods
- extracting methods
- other stuff, called "refactoring" in software development

Since I have a [JetBrains ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) license, which is a special tool exactly for that kind of work, I was glad I found [Visual Micro](https://www.visualmicro.com/). Visual Micro is a plugin to Visual Studio, adding Arduino support. At the same time it maintains all capabilities of other plugins, such as ReSharper.

I want to ensure that my toolchain is free, so that others (especially children and youngsters) can follow. In that case, one would use Visual Studio Community Edition and not use ReSharper but use VS's built-in refactoring capabilities.

Unfortunately, the license conditions of Visual Micro have changed and it's no longer free. That's why I'm looking for an alternative to Visual Micro, which adds Arduino support to Visual Studio.

Requirements:

- add Arduino support to Visual Studio
- be able to download and install Arduino Libraries
- additional board support through board managers (like ESP8266, NodeMCU, ESP32)
- has a Serial monitor